# Rails - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "customers" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.0.4,  Ruby 2.5.1, Postgres, Ubuntu 18.04

I've read several posts here in stackoverflow similar to my problem, but nothing that helps me or is similar to mine.

Back story

I developed a personal app on my laptop.  I pushed to github and heroku and everything works just fine.   I wanted to be able to work on this app on my desktop computer also.  It has the same setup as my laptop: both run Ubuntu 18.04, both have the same versions of ruby and rails, both have postgres.

I cloned the app from github onto my desktop.  Problem: any rails or rake command I run generates this error.

```
/home/jdc44/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:88:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "customers" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"customers"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
             (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
               WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
                     col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"customers"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Since it states `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR...`, I "assumed" it must be a database setup issue.

On my desktop, in postgres, I created the same databases, users and passwords as is on my laptop.

```
postgres=# \l
                                           List of databases
          Name          |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges     
------------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------
 myapp                  | myapp      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 myapp_development      | cowan      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/cowan                +
                        |            |          |             |             | cowan=CTc/cowan          +
                        |            |          |             |             | myapp=CTc/cowan
 myapp_test             | myapp      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/myapp                +
                        |            |          |             |             | myapp=CTc/myapp
 postgres               | postgres   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

With the exception of what is displayed in the `Access privileges` column, the lines with myapp... are identical to my laptop output.

`database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: myapp
  password: *****

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Again, any `rake` or `rails` command nets me this error. i.e: `rake db:migrate` or `rails console`.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

jc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I read through the error output again and found this line:

`/home/jdc44/Websites/myapp/spec/factories/job.rb:2:in`block in '`.

```
job.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job, :class => Job do
    customer_id FactoryGirl.create(:customer).id 
    ...
```

Because the error was on the `customers` table, I figured it had to have something to do with the `jobs` spec, since jobs and customers have a relationship:  `customer has many jobs`  The jobs spec has this:

```
before do
    @job = FactoryGirl.build(:job)
  end
```

For some reason, changing the `build` to `create` made everything work.  Not sure why, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run your migrations:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that.  `rake ...` and `rails ...` commands all give me this error.

Comment: Can you just try blowing away your database and recreating it?